# What do IRQ, RTS, DTR & DSR mean here?

Tags: linux, serial-port, rs232

Got the below output on my linux. What do TX, RX, IRQ, RTS, DTR, DSR mean here in this context. I have read about Data Terminal Ready & Request to Send, but need help in understanding them in the example shown below. Do the numbers next to TX and RX mean the current number of characters in the respective buffer?

```
cat /proc/tty/driver/serial 
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:
0: uart:16550A port:000003F8 irq:4 tx:0 rx:0
1: uart:16550A port:000002F8 irq:3 tx:111780 rx:1321 RTS|DTR|DSR
```

Comment: *"Do the numbers next to TX and RX mean the current number of characters in the respective buffer?"*  Not characters.. bytes.. but yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at hardware attributes, statistics and status reported by a Linux serial terminal (e.g. UART or USART) device driver.

> Do the numbers next to TX and RX mean the current number of characters in the respective buffer?

The numbers represent the number of frames that have been handled (transmitted and received respectively) by the device.
The frame size is configurable; the frame size could be for a full byte of 8 bits, or just 7 bits for ASCII characters.
The frame size is often also referred to as the character size, especially in UART/USART datasheets, which do not presume that "character" equates to ASCII codes.

This frame is delimited by the `start` and `stop` bits.

> What do TX, RX, IRQ, RTS, DTR, DSR mean here in this context.

The `irq` is the (hardware) [interrupt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_request_(PC_architecture)) number that this device is using.

The active state of attached [control lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#Data_and_control_signals) (e.g. RTS, DTR, DSR)  is reported.
If the name of the control line is listed, then that line is in an asserted state.
If the name of the control line is not listed, then that line is not asserted or is not even connected.
But the report of a control line could still be bogus (i.e. it's listed but not connected) if it is not properly (electrically) pulled down/up and left "floating".

---

The `port:` indicates that this device is accessible at the given [I/O port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O) address.
Other devices might instead use memory-mapped I/O addresses, designated with `MMIO:`.

---

To see why your reference to a *"buffer"* is ambiguous, refer to the article [Serial drivers](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/serial/serial.html) for serial terminal and device driver relationships, and the various buffers involved.

---

**Addendum**

Besides the frame counts for transmit and receive, other (receiver) statistics may be reported (when greater than zero):

```
fe:   framing errors (stop bit not found) 
pe:   parity errors  
brk:  break conditions  
oe:   receiver overrun errors
bo:   buffer overrun errors (not all drivers accumulate this number)
```

These receiver statistics are typically counts of hardware-detected events, so consult the relevant datasheet for the exact how & what the hardware is reporting.

Besides the RTS, DTR, and DSR control lines that you mention, the CTS, CD, and RI can also be reported.

This information is reported by the Linux kernel routine **uart_line_info()** in the **drivers/tty/serial/serial_core.c** file.

Comment: Great explanation. Will take time to consume it and get back, if I have questions. Thank you.